# How do I make a button show and hide text when clicked and why does getElement not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have done all the HTML and CSS but the JavaScript part is confusing me. How do I make a button hide or show text when clicked?

There is an error that comes up on the console as well. It says that `getElement` is not defined. I've also tried using `getElementByClassName` but the error message still comes up.

The error says `Uncaught ReferenceError: getElement is not defined` and the same for `getElementByClassName`

--

In the code:

`nav-btn` = the button that should to toggle the text

`nav-links` = the text that should to show up

--

The JavaScript code:

```
const links = getElement(".nav-links")
const navBtn = getElementByClassName('nav-btn')

links.style.display = 'none';

navBtn.onclick = function () {
    if (links.style.display !== "none") {
        links.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        links.style.display = "block"
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Also what do I do about the getElement problem?

Comment: Is `getElement()` your custom function? Because that's not native to JS. And here's the documentation for [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). For one, there's an "S" in the method name. Two, it returns an HTMLCollection, which is not a single element, so you'll need to specify which item you want in that collection. Get familiar with how to find things in the documentation.

Comment: You may use `document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links');`and loop through it to reset display. Add your HTML if you need further help.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not a global function, you need to call it as `document.getElementsByClassName`. (`getElement` does not exist however - it looks like you want `document.querySelector`.)

Comment: Thanks I did not know that `getElement` is not native to it because I was using what was used in a video tutorial that I had previously done.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getElement` is not defined, you must be using it as native JS function, which is not available.
If you want to select element with className, you can use `querySelector`

```
const links = document.querySelector('.nav-links')
```

And `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of nodes, not just single element.
So Change it to `querySelector` for your use case

```
const navBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-btn')
```

Comment: Thank you I did not realise this at first but now I know.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment below your post `getElement` isn't a native JS DOM method which is why the error is appearing. Personally I would use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and add a [`listener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the button. And then use CSS, and [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), to [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a `show` class off and on. It makes for shorter more readable code.

```js
const links = document.querySelector(".nav-links")
const navBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-btn')

navBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  links.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.nav-links { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="nav-links">Nav links</div>
<button class="nav-btn">Toggle the nav!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. How does the `.show` code work if it is not part of my HTML? I thought that you could only use CSS on items that have already been declared in the HTML code.

Comment: SO snippets work a little differently. If you add a [`<link>` in your HTML header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) to your CSS it will work @tices